# Powering microcontroller with a capacitor

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, capacitor, supercapacitor, esr

I have a ESP32-SOLO-1 microcontroller mounted on a moving part of a machine which moves in a circle. The idea is to power it with a capacitor and then charge the capacitor in a fixed location when the MCU/capacitor part comes around (for example via some sort of sliding contacts connected to a power brick.)

The main problem is the charging of the capacitor, as it has in the current configuration around 0.14 s to charge and it has to last about 8 s with a load of 0.04 A at 3.3V until it charges again (except the first time it goes around the MCU has to boot and it requires 0.1 A for about 1 s.)

I used so far a 0.47 F supercap with a rating of 5.5 V ([here the datasheet.)](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000473103DS01/datenblatt-473103-thomsen-473103-gold-cap-kondensator-047-f-55-v-30-o-x-h-215-mm-x-10-mm-1-st.pdf) I already had with a MCP1700-3302E-TO voltage regulator to have a fixed 3.3 V output. The cap has an ESR of about 16 ohm which in my understanding is far too much for charghing it in such a short time.

My idea was to use [this](https://www.conrad.de/de/p/jianghai-ecs1ebz333mt6p23540-elektrolyt-kondensator-snapin-10-mm-33000-f-25-v-20-x-h-35-mm-x-40-mm-1-st-446260.html#productDownloads) capacitor --> 0.033F 25V and a very low ESR (0.027 ohm in the datasheet) charged with a 24V power brick and power the MCU with a DC-DC converter ([this)](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000156671DS02/datenblatt-156671-tracopower-tsr-1-2433-dcdc-wandler-print-24-vdc-33-vdc-1-a-75-w-anzahl-ausgaenge-1-x.pdf) that outputs 3.3 V.

What are your thoughts on this? Am I completly wrong or could it work? Do you have any suggestions on how to make it work?

EDIT: The MCU evaluates and sends data from a Hall sensor, which is used to mesure the distance of a magnet. So I would rather not have electromagnetic interference and therefore use "touching" parts. **Also the goal is to avoid if possibly using a battery.**

Comment: What about a slip ring? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring#:~:text=A%20slip%20ring%20(in%20electrical,such%20as%20in%20a%20motor.

Comment: The MCU unit moves in a circle but not on itself. As if it was mounted on the edge of a big wheel that spins and the MCU goes by the charging point only one time per revolution of the wheel

Comment: Can you use a transforming action or induction. You can't mount brushes around the wheel and wire them back? (which is what a slipring would be). Also consider a battery.

Comment: The MCU evaluates and sends data from a Hall Sensor, which is used to mesure the distance of a magnet. So I would rather not have electomagnetical interference and therefore use "touching" parts.

Comment: What is the RPM? 7.5RPM? Because brushes make sparks which could interfere with your radio (which I assume is what you are using to transmit data). Powering RF from a noisy, unstable supply and transmitting when sparks are present might be asking for trouble.

Comment: Rather than RPM the brushes would pass by at around 1.5 m/s and yes I am using Bluetooth LE to transmit the data.

Comment: It is not best idea because capacitor voltage going down due to discharge. You will get pulsation . Smooth it may be complicated. Some battery simpler solution.

Comment: I know but the whole point was to avoid using a battery. Maybe I could use some smaller capacitors before the DC-DC converter to smooth the Voltage?

Comment: Smaller caps won't smooth anything by definition. How do you plan on smoothing out the voltage of a big cap with small caps? You can't. At some point, the DC-DC converter brick and all the enormous capacitors you throw into the spinning wheel, plus the brushes, are going to be heavier and more complicated than just a battery. It's easy enough to try though at your slow speeds. The most complicated part is mounting the brushes, but leave room for a battery in case it doesn't work out.

Comment: What is using the 40mA the hall sensor or the MCU?  40mA seems a little high given the functionality you are describing.

Comment: @user4574 I assume the radio.

Comment: @DKNguyen That's a good possibility, but unless this machine is really huge, one would think that here is probably a lower power radio given the short transmit distance.

Comment: Depending how long contact is made for, you may want significantly larger caps (>5x) on the fixed brushed which are charged up and ready so that you can immediately discharge into the super cap on your moving brush without having their own voltage dragged down by the cap on the moving brush. Otherwise your stationary supply may not react quickly enough and get bogged down, but not so big that your stationary supply can't handle all the output capacitance (or you need to have a series resistor so the stationary supply gracefully charge up and top off the caps on the fixed brush).

Comment: _"except the first time it goes around the MCU has to boot and it requires 0.1 A for about 1 s."_ - Can you position the contacts to fully charge the capacitor before the part starts moving? Alternatively, can the MCU be held in a low power mode or disconnected until the capacitor has had time to get an initial charge?

Comment: @user4574 yes the 40mA are for the BLE data tranmission and the MCU. The machine is quite large and using this microcontroller simplifies other parts of the project such as data acquisition and compatibility with the software I am currently using

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for the answer. Thas is a really interesting solution that I might try out.

Comment: @BruceAbbott yes that is definetly a possibility. The MCU could run for some time on low power mode until the cap is fully charged.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds plausible.

Maybe you could use a Qi transmitter/receiver to produce 5V and use a simple LDO regulator down to 3.3V. I'm not sure they would switch on fast enough and give enough current for long enough to work. You would need (say) 1A for less than 500msec to keep an average 40mA going, which sounds to me like it might be worth investigation.

Regardless of how you get 5V to the target, a super-capacitor such as the AVX[SCMT32F755SRBA0](http://datasheets.avx.com/AVX-SCM.pdf) 7.5F 5.5V with 90m\$\Omega\$ ESR might do the trick (charged to 5V and with an LDO regulator) with room to spare. If you use brushes, maybe you can inhibit communication during the noisy bits and add a current limiter to the 5V supply to keep the peak current tame.